# Change column to required in response of another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation

I have two columns: `Valor de Estatus` and `Comments`

`Valor de Estatus` is a select box with values:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comments column is a multi line and is not required as default

I want to make column `Comments` required when user pick `Estatus` with value `4`

**UPDATE**

I look into another questions you can go to list item validation and apply formula. Problem is you cant select multi line there. Is there any solution can I apply here?

Formula can be something like:

```
=IF([Valor de Estatus]="4",IF([Comments]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

But I cant pick comments because is a multi line, what can I do there?

Answer (score 0):

List validation doesn’t support Multiple lines of text field, so you could use PreSaveAction for this.
Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreSaveAction() {
        //City is choice field
        var option = $('select[title="City"]').val();
        if (option == "Paris") {
            //Comment is mutiple line text field
            var mutipleTxt=$('div[id^="Comment"]').text();
            alert(mutipleTxt);
            if (mutipleTxt.trim() == "Rich text editor​Rich text editor​".trim()) {
                return false;
                alert("Comment can't be null");
            }
            else
                return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/